# Android Stuio not show or download sdk Only after changing the language

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I use android studio 4 and my window 10 language is Arabic if I build or download SDK they were problems for download sdk or gradle
so if I change location to United States and language to English it run and download sdk with out any problems

My question is, How I solution this problem with don't change location and language

This is with out change any thing sdk only shows downloaded

[This is with out change any thing sdk only shows downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQEun.png)

[This is with out change any thing sdk only shows downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCEvV.png)

and this after change location

[Change location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC7xq.png)

[SDK list is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwbI2.png)

[SDK list is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2sm0.png)